# Portmapping a vector to a std_in in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I have a component with about 30 some inputs, and I have a vector with the same amount. I want to port map the component along the lines of

`component port map(vector(0), vector(1), .... ,vector(31));`

is there a way to do this quicker than just writing out every slot in the vector?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you will have to enumerate every slot in the vector at least once.   If you are doing this in multiple places, you can create a wrapper for the existing component so it accepts a vector and then directly assign the vector to the wrapper.  Then you only have to enumerate the vector elements once (in the wrapper).

I have also used custom types and conversion functions to allow 'prettier' code.  You can create custom aggregate types and use them logically (ie: memory.addr, memory.data, memory.wr) and [un]bundle them (to|from) a standard_logic_vector with a function (so you can tie them to a standard register or FIFO interface, for instance), but you don't mention what sort of constraints you're working with.